# 個人情報データの受け取り方を教えていただきたい

Tags: database, データ構造, データベース設計

### 回答していただきたい内容2点

1. (A)の内容のやり方で合っているのか教えていただきたい。
2. もし今回のようなケースでも下記の(B)の方法で受け取れるやり方があれば教えていただきたい。

### 質問に至る経緯

データ分析の実務経験を積むために、知り合いのお店からデータをもらい、データ分析を行いたいと思っています。しかし、このデータには顧客名、住所などの個人情報が入っています。個人情報について調べるとこの個人情報を扱うには私は、『第三者提供』に該当し、以下の(A)(B)のどちらかをしなければいけないと思いました。

- (A) データ利用目的を伝え、あらかじめ各顧客の同意を得る ＆ 一定事項の記録(いつ・誰の・どんな情報を・誰に)
- (B) データを「匿名加工情報」へ変換する ＆ 一定事項の記録(いつ・誰の・どんな情報を・誰に)

### 私の思い

私は(A)は顧客全員に同意を取らなければならないので大変な為、(B)を行いたいと思うのですが、私がデータをもらう知り合いはデータを「匿名加工情報」へ変換することができないので今回のようなケースでは(A)を選択するしか方法が無いのかな？と思っています。
個人で顧客からデータを受け取りの業務をしている方々が今回の私のようなケースではどのように個人情報データに対応しているのか教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 匿名加工情報と著名加工情報では大差あるような・・・あとその加工を人間が手で行うってよかったんだっけ？（加工を行う人物は個人情報を目にするわけで）

Comment: 興味深い内容ではありますが、現状の質問内容はどちらかというとプログラミングというより法律寄りの話に見え、個人的にはオフトピックかなとも思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

｢私は企業ではないため」が何を指しているのかよくわからないのですが、あなたが第三者としてデータ提供を受けるのであれば「知り合いのお店」が各個人から第三者提供の承諾をとってもらうか、承諾なしで提供できる形にデータを加工してもらうしかありません。

｢匿名」を｢著名」と読み違えられるあたり個人で判断されるにはとても不安な状況ですので、知識があるかたにきちんと相談された方がよいように思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。他の方々もおっしゃられている通り場違いの質問をしてしまったようで申し訳ありません。個人情報保護委員会に直接相談してみます。